# Is there a way to copy text from emacs with faces in Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs, colors, copy-paste, emacs-faces

Every now and then I run into a situation when I need to email a piece of code from emacs. When I paste text into my email program (not emacs), all the color highlighting is lost. This is especially disappointing when pasting from `org-mode`, which relies heavily on colors for readability. It would be good to preserve font faces.

Is there a way to do this? I am looking for output similar to that of `ps-print-buffer-with-faces`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose your email program can handle html, try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`htmlfontify-buffer`, which converts the contents of the current buffer (with faces) to css-styled html.

Comment: Works very well, currently part of emacs. I had to upgrade from emacs-22.3. Thanks.